# issue with split payments paypal (adaptive payments is restricted)

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments

Running into issue for split payments with-in app.
Process: a) receive a payment every time app is downloaded on our platform b) automatically split received payment 50/50 to my bank account & to the app developer's account

Looked at PayPal and Stripe but they do not have automatic payment splits or are very restrictive to businesses (adaptive payments are restricted to certain businesses?).  Any one come across a solution to this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PayPal do have Adaptive Payment API where it allows the payment to be split to a few party upon receiving, and it could be use by any country where PayPal is offered to accepted. Unfortunately PayPal are deprecating this API starting from December 2017.

Alternatively you can accept payment as per normal, and getting it split after that.

I forgot to mention, PayPal now with Braintree has a similar API just like Adaptive where they called it MarketPlace. According to the documentation 101, Marketplace now offer to all country that Braintree is accepted.

Link : https://www.braintreepayments.com/en-my/products/braintree-marketplace

Comment: how to split it after accepting payment?  This is harder if we have hundreds of downloads a day- we cannot manually split each one and send to bank account.

Comment: @3eye In Adaptive Payments the split is defined when you create the payment using the `Pay` operation on the API. There you enter all the recipients and what amount they get off the total transaction value. But you might want to take a look into their new "PayPal for Marketplaces" solution.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/orders/integration-guide/

```
"partner_fee_details": {
    "receiver": {
      "email": "partner@example.com"
    },
```